# Provide text hosting for long contextual text-files supporting a question

Tags: discussion, attachment

One usability issue of Stack Overflow is that the first answer to a question is often several page-scrolls away from the top of a page. In between you may get large areas of code-snippets that maybe should not be there, but nobody is there to clean them up, stacktraces, logfiles, explanations about context, and then a trail of comments (about how the question is too long).

This is in contrast of the promise of the Stack Overflow About page:

> Ask questions, get answers, no distractions

Also some people host text files on other sites, but that has the risk of the question becoming useless because the linked content does not exist any more.

While it would be nice if people could be motivated to spend hours optimizing screen real estate for their question without losing important detail, it might be better to give them a quick way to add files as attachments so that they do not block the space between the title and the first answer.

Comment: And you would prevent malware in these attachments how?

Comment: They would be text only.

Comment: I guess the soft problem here is some folks just dump *all* the logs, with no cleanup or any idea what they're doing.

Comment: How to differentiate between "text-only" and the others? By file extension? From the content? How about non-ascii characters (or, Unicode)?

Comment: Files would be stores as text, with fixed extension (e.g. txt) and a random filename, same as imgur does I guess. Not like email attachments where users choose some filename.

Answer (score 2):

> In between you may get large areas of code-snippets that maybe should not be there, but nobody is there to clean them up, stacktraces, logfiles, explanations about context, and then a trail of comments

Sometimes those are important for those who want to help, and many times questions are downvoted and closed because they **don't have those**.

- Code snippets: crucial in order to know what OP tried.
- Stack traces: very helpful to debug. Sometimes OP needs help with that too.
- Log file: same as stack trace, when it's not enough.
- Explanations about context: maybe the most crucial part, which explains why each part is there, what OP tried, and where they're stuck.
- Comments: also useful many times, and if not you can always flag.

So you suggest to push all the above into separate text attachment, which needs extra click to open? Sorry, I strongly disagree. All the above should be part of the question, when needed.

Of course that when the question is just a wall of text/code/logs it should be closed and deleted, having the ability to hide this behind attachment won't improve the quality even a bit.

Comment: I want to offer freedom to have a third alternative to put everything into the question thus pushing down the answers 3 screens, and leaving out useful details. With a good question, the best answer is read 1000 times more often than the question by site visitors. Yet text walls force all those visitors to scroll over text that is largely irrelevant once a good answer has been found.

Comment: @tkruse so for those cases, a much better solution is adding a link to first/latest answer somewhere in the top, e.g. in the sidebar below "viewed" counter.

Comment: I am not a UX designer, so I cannot say which visual solution ought to be best to reduce distance from top-of-screen to answers. I'll grant you that functionally this would help. As a UX novice, I believe putting the most valuable piece information onto the first screen is a good guideline.